# File_get_contents, curl not working

Tags: php, api, curl

Something strange is going on, and I would like to know why.

On this url: http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json, which works well in the browser, but when I tried to retrieve the content with php:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json');
```

printed nothing, with `var_dump(...) = string(0) ""`, so i went a little further and used:

```
function get_page($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

echo get_page('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json');
```

Also printed nothing, so i tried python (3.X):

```
import requests
print(requests.get('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json').text)
```

And WORKED. Why is this happening? What's going on?

Comment: are you using this on a server or on your own pc? could be that the php module for those function is not set enabled which would indeed occur in blank.

Comment: you're just assuming success. `echo` won't print out the boolean false that you'd get back on failure. use `var_dump` instead.

Comment: Nop, the api it's on an external server, and i also tried `echo file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548007/file-get-contents-curl-not-working?noredirect=1#comment62584729_37548007');` and it worked

Comment: Result of `var_dump`: `string(0) ""`, i tried this too

Comment: try playing with the options, especially try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);` before the curl_exec

Comment: Nop, did nothing, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they're blocking the user agent, or lack thereof, considering that php curl and `file_get_contents` doesn't seem to set the value in the request header.

You can fake this by setting it to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1`

```
<?php
function get_page($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

echo get_page('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json');
```

Comment: Thanks it was that indeed. Just out of curiosity, what is the default `user_agent` and why it was working with `curl` on console and with python 3.x?

Comment: I don't *think* php curl or file_get_contents has one. I created a test page that only has `var_dump($_SERVER)` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT` was not set. When I manually set the agent as in my answer, it showed as expected. When running curl from console, it sets the agent as `curl/7.35.0` in my case

Comment: Thanks, but it's strange that with `console curl/python 3.x` works. I would like to know why. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Do a call to a script that dumps request headers, to inspect the python variants request.

Comment: @fungusanthrax it identifies the browser to the server so that the server can potentially give different content based on user agent, such as a mobile site (before the days of responsive design). In some cases, servers ignore requests from bots or if the user agent string isn't set at all, they interpret it as something not worth answering, like a possible DDOS attack.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same behaviour.

Fetching the URL using the CLI Curl worked for me.

I then wrote a script with a `file_get_contents` call to another script that dumped all request headers to a file using `getallheaders`:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/tmp/request_headers.txt', var_export(getallheaders(),true));
```

Output of file:

```
array (
  'Host' => 'localhost',
)
```

I then inspected the curl request headers,

```
$ curl -v URL
```

And tried adding one at a time to the file_get_contents request. It turned out a User agent header was needed.

```
<?php
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>
      "User-Agent: examplebot\r\n"
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false , $context);
```

This gave me a useful response.

Comment: Thanks, any ideia why the `curl -v http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json` on terminal and with python worked without specifying an user agent?

Comment: CLI curl passes a user agent header.